# vuejs laravel authentication page blocking

Tags: vue.js

what I want to do is to prevent the user from entering the login page again if he is logged in,
Likewise, if the login process is successful, the login page will be blocked.

If the user is not logged in, he cannot go to pages such as home about. Likewise, if the login is successful, it will be possible to return to the login or register page.

app.vue

```
created() {
        this.$store.dispatch("initAuth")
    },
```

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>login</h1>

        <div>
            <input type="email" v-model="user.email">
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="password" v-model="user.password">
        </div>
        <div>
            <button @click="login">Giriş Yap</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    name: "Login",
    data() {
        return {
            user: {
                email: null,
                password: null,
            },
            isUser: false
        }
    },
    methods: {
        login() {
            this.$store.dispatch("login", {...this.user, isUser: this.isUser})
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

router.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import store from '../store'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            name: 'home',
            component: () => import('@/views/Home.vue'),
            meta: {
                requiresAuth: true
            },
        },
        {
            path: '/about',
            name: 'about',
            component: () => import('@/views/About.vue'),
            meta: {
                requiresAuth: true,
            },
        },
        {
            path: '/login',
            name: 'login',
            component: () => import('@/views/Login.vue'),

        },
        {
            path: '/register',
            name: 'register',
            component: () => import('@/views/Register.vue'),
        },
        {
            path: '/error-404',
            name: 'error-404',
            component: () => import('@/views/error/Error404.vue'),
        },
        {
            path: '*',
            redirect: 'error-404',
        },
    ],
})


router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {

        if (!store.getters.isAuthenticated) {
            next({name: 'login'})
        } else {
            next()
        }
    } else {
        next() // make sure to always call next()!
    }

});

export default router
```

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import axios from "axios";
import router from '../router';

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        token: "",
    },
    mutations: {
        setToken(state, token) {
            state.token = token
        },
        clearToken(state) {
            state.token = ""
        }
    },
    actions: {
        initAuth({commit, dispatch}) {
            let token = localStorage.getItem("token")
            if (token) {
                commit('setToken', token)
            } else {
                router.push('/login')
                commit('clearToken')
                //return false;
            }
        },
        login({commit, dispatch, state}, autData) {

            return axios.post(
                '/api/login', {
                    email: autData.email,
                    password: autData.password
                })
                .then(response => {
                    commit('setToken', response.data.token)
                    localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token)
                    router.push('/about')
                    console.log(response)
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error)
                })
        },
        register({commit, dispatch, state}, autData) {

            return axios.post(
                '/api/register', {
                    name: autData.name,
                    email: autData.email,
                    password: autData.password,
                    password_confirmation: autData.password_confirmation
                })
                .then(response => {
                    router.push('/about')
                    commit('setToken', response.data.token)
                    console.log(response)
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error.response.data.errors);
                })
        },
        logout({commit}) {
            commit('clearToken')
            localStorage.removeItem('token')
            router.push('/');
        },
        setTimeoutTimer({dispatch}, expiresIn) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                dispatch("logout")
            }, expiresIn)
        }

    },
    getters: {
        isAuthenticated(state) {
            return state.token !== ""
        }
    },
    modules: {},
})
```

Answer (score 0):

add a new meta key `requiresNotAuth` for login and register routes then change `beforeEach` content like this

```
if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {

    if (!store.getters.isAuthenticated) {
        next({name: 'login'})
    } else {
        next()
    }
} 
else if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresNotAuth)) {

    if (store.getters.isAuthenticated) {
        next({name: 'home'})
    } 
    else {
        next()
    }
} 
else {
    next() // make sure to always call next()!
}
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but can you write me in detail how to do this? I'm new to vuejs.

Comment: Ok I will not do the job for you but yes I can give you more informations.
For now in your router file you have some routes with a meta key `requireAuth`,right ?  next follow my answer